# Depended controls framework

Tags: controls

I am looking for client-side javascript plugin for jquery(preferred, or maybe other framework) that can implement the dependency between controls.

Here is general requirements:

- the dependency shall be implemented in declarative form (settings, mapping, xml...)
- the displaying of the next control shall be dependent on input of previous control(s)
- one-to-one, one-to-many dependencies support
- actions (show, hide, disable, set value...) on depended controls.
- ajax calls

It is too complicated requirements and its can be simplified, but depended controls should be present.

I think, it can be useful, because everyone meet so stuffs in their UI.

[image]

Comment: I think this question is a bit more technical than this site is meant for.

Comment: @Sruly♦ On the technical site (stackoverflow) it was not answered. :(

Comment: Can you post a link to the SO question?

Comment: @Patrick McElhaney♦ it has been deleted. i have found an answer myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UI Triggers](http://dev.eclipse.org/blogs/yvesyang/2009/10/12/xwt-ui-trigger-1/) will resolve this problem:

- UI Property trigger
- Multiple UI Property triggers
- Data Property trigger
- Multiple Data Property trigger
- UI Event trigger

Answer (score 2):

This looks pretty good. (I haven't used it myself)

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/20/cascadingdropdown-jquery-plugin-for-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: +1 your help is always appreciated, thank you for attempt.